Issue with mocking bugsnag notify method in vue vitest
In Vitest how could I import and mock Bugsnag notify method so that I can check if it is called with a specific error in the failure workflow
TypeError: [Function] is not a spy or a call to a spy!
expect(Bugsnag.notify).toHaveBeenCalled()

Error: [vitest] No "default" export is defined on the "@bugsnag/js" mock. Did you forget to return it from "vi.mock"?
If you need to partially mock a module, you can use "vi.importActual" inside:

Self-answers are welcome on SO but make sure they conform the SO rules and don't serve just as a prompt for an answer, and an answer is usable for other readers. Yours is code-only and contains no explanation except the comment

import Bugsnag from '@bugsnag/js'
import { mutate } from '~/generated/graphql'
import { describe, it, expect, vi, afterEach } from 'vitest'

describe('MyTestCodeWithBugsnagMocking', () => {
  vi.mock('@bugsnag/js', async () => {
    const actual = await vi.importActual('@bugsnag/js')
    return {
      ...actual,
      default: { notify: vi.fn() }, // Ensure the default export includes the required methods
    }
  })

  afterEach(() => {
    vi.clearAllMocks()
  })

  it('should not call bugsnag notify', async () => {
    await someAsyncAction('test-id')
    expect(Bugsnag.notify).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
  })

  it('should call bugsnag notify with error', async () => {
    const errorMessage = 'Some error occurred'

    await someAsyncAction('invalid-id')
    expect(Bugsnag.notify).toHaveBeenCalledWith(errorMessage)
  })

  it('should handle exceptions and notify bugsnag', async () => {
    const exceptionMessage = 'Exception occurred'

    await someAsyncAction(null)    
    expect(Bugsnag.notify).toHaveBeenCalledWith(exceptionMessage)
  })
})


is this the solution or part of the problem? if the latter, please update your question to include this piece of code

@EdgarOrtega this is solution, to that problem
